# How to revert merging of two branches in perforce p4v client?

Tags: perforce, p4v

Let's assume this scenario. We have 3 branches a,b,c in our perforce depot. First of all, I merged branch "a" into branch "c". Then I merged branch "b" into branch "c". Then I submitted both the merges.

After that, I came to know that the branch "a" was a faulty branch with errors. That was a mistake to merge the branch "a" with branch "c". I was supposed to merge only branch "b" with branch "c".

We don't use command line tool. We are using p4v GUI client. I have no clue how to revert those two merges and then merge the branch "b" only with branch "c".

Please help me get out of here with some idea. Thanks in advance.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the Submitted changelist in P4V from the merge of a -> c and right-click and choose 'Rollback'.

For more information about how to undo an integration via the Rollback feature in Perforce, go here:

```
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/How-To-Rollback-An-Integration
```

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists/

Comment: I have to choose "Roll back" or "back out"?

Comment: For integrations (merges/copy/branch), use "Rollback".

Comment: Ohh. Thats great. This will help. Will the rollback command completely revert the integration?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that 'Revert' is for a pending integration that has not been submitted. 'Rollback' is for submitted integrations. Please check out that 'How to Rollback An Integration' knowledge base article I sent you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check that article.

Comment: Sure. In case of any other help related to p4v, i will ask you. Thanks again